# Turbolinks: javascript codes inside body tag are not executed as they should

Tags: javascript, turbolinks

I am trying to add Turbolinks power to my website but I am currently facing a problem. I have `script` tags that used to be in the `head` section which was executed on page load of specific pages. These scripts should be executed once and on their specific page only. When I tried Turbolinks, these scripts were not executed at all unless they exist in the initial page (the first page loaded from the server). So I moved the scripts to the end of the `body` section of my HTML page. Here are my findings:

1- Normal `script` tags:
This resulted in executing the code multiple times. So if I load the page once it will execute correctly, if I navigate away from the page and then come back to it, the code will execute twice. If I do that again then it will execute 3 times ... etc. The code  is being executed from sources that starts with `VM` and ends with 5 digits, example `VM29823` that are created in chrome each time it visits a page with `script` tag inside of its `body`. These scripts are executed even if you are navigating to a different page, for example if I visit page A with script SA then SA will be executed onload of other pages B and C. Which is, of course, not desirable.

2- `script` tags with `data-turbolinks-eval=false`:
In that case the `script` is only executed only if that script was called from the initial page (The first load of the website), which is a similar behaviour of adding the script to the head section instead of the body.

I need to execute my scripts only once and to their corresponding pages.

Please help.

Comment: The Turbolinks documentation says that `<script>` tags should be put in the `<head>` section.

Comment: @Barmar True, but turbolinks only updates what is inside the body tag. Hence, if I want to add certain script for 1 page only it have to be inside the body.

Comment: @wael34218 have you come up with any solution since? I'm trying to attempt something similar by placing my page-specific JavaScript inside the `<body>`, while keeping my other assets that should be served by Turbolinks in the `<head>`. But I'm running in to the same problems as you.

Comment: Hm unfortunately, it seems that trying to implement page-specific JavaScript loading in the `<body>`is just not kosher with Turbolinks at all. According to this blog post (http://staal.io/blog/2013/01/18/dangers-of-turbolinks/), it's really easy to mess up the Global scope if you don't strictly follow the Turbolinks way (i.e. putting all scripts in the `<head>` section).

Answer (score 0):

To fix you page specific script problem, I think you may solve it by adding data-turbolinks-track=true with this code (in your specific_page.html.erb), placed within `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
    <%=  javascript_include_tag "path/to/specific_page_js", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    ...
</head>
```

A small disadvantage of this is that turbolinks will request the page to reload when it see the new `<script>` in the specific page.